# Android app crashes on launch on updating Firebase sdk from version 5.4.4 to 6.8.0

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I tried to update my unity firebase sdk from version 5.4.4 to version 6.8.0 and i don't have any error when building the app, but when i tried to launch the app it simply crashes. I tried to check for log and i got the following issue :

```
12-12 17:11:00.295: D/AndroidRuntime(32084): Shutting down VM
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): Process: com.myapp.dev, PID: 32084
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.voxelbusters.nativeplugins.extensions.FileProviderExtended: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.voxelbusters.nativeplugins.extensions.FileProviderExtended" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.dev-vvwykEqMMsoxQa7Hbz5x9g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.dev-vvwykEqMMsoxQa7Hbz5x9g==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.myapp.dev-vvwykEqMMsoxQa7Hbz5x9g==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib/hw, /system/vendor/lib]]
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6454)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6002)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5914)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1739)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)

12-12 17:11:00.295: D/AndroidRuntime(32084): Shutting down VM
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): Process: com.myapp.dev, PID: 32084
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.voxelbusters.nativeplugins.extensions.FileProviderExtended: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.voxelbusters.nativeplugins.extensions.FileProviderExtended" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.dev-vvwykEqMMsoxQa7Hbz5x9g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.dev-vvwykEqMMsoxQa7Hbz5x9g==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.myapp.dev-vvwykEqMMsoxQa7Hbz5x9g==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib/hw, /system/vendor/lib]]
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6454)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6002)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5914)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1739)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6710)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.voxelbusters.nativeplugins.extensions.FileProviderExtended" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.dev-vvwykEqMMsoxQa7Hbz5x9g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.dev-vvwykEqMMsoxQa7Hbz5x9g==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.myapp.dev-vvwykEqMMsoxQa7Hbz5x9g==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib/hw, /system/vendor/lib]]
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6439)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): ... 10 more
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/content/FileProvider;
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): ... 12 more
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.dev-vvwykEqMMsoxQa7Hbz5x9g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.dev-vvwykEqMMsoxQa7Hbz5x9g==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.myapp.dev-vvwykEqMMsoxQa7Hbz5x9g==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib/hw, /system/vendor/lib]]
```

Please help me solve this.

Comment: Have you tried `Force Resolve`?

Answer (score 0):

I think some dependency is missing. Try this

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, yes i have tried that and  few suggestion from online as well but nothing is working out

Comment: Do you see the `Resolution Successful` message?

Answer (score 0):

So, to echo @gameDev_Unity's intuition, it does look like some library is missing from the lines:

```
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.voxelbusters.nativeplugins.extensions.FileProviderExtended: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.voxelbusters.nativeplugins.extensions.FileProviderExtended" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.dev-vvwykEqMMsoxQa7Hbz5x9g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.dev-vvwykEqMMsoxQa7Hbz5x9g==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.myapp.dev-vvwykEqMMsoxQa7Hbz5x9g==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib/hw, /system/vendor/lib]]
```

and

```
12-12 17:11:00.305: E/AndroidRuntime(32084): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.dev-vvwykEqMMsoxQa7Hbz5x9g==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.dev-vvwykEqMMsoxQa7Hbz5x9g==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.myapp.dev-vvwykEqMMsoxQa7Hbz5x9g==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib/hw, /system/vendor/lib]]
```

Since the issue is around `android.support` and Firebase uses [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) now, I bet that you either have an old Firebase library still hanging on or another plugin that uses Android features trying to use the old support libraries.

I would suggest turning on Jetifier in the "Play Services Resolver":
[image]

Which should automatically find and detect uses of `android.support` and convert them to `androidx`. You can read more about Jetifier [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier), but you shouldn't have to execute the command line. This may not help if something in your game is calling [Android stuff directly via the JNI](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJNI.html), so you may want to search your C# files for `android.support` as well.

If that doesn't work, I suggest switching Play Services Resolver to patching your gradle file (see [this article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-manage-your-native-ios-and-android-dependencies-in-unity-like-firebase-921659843aef?source=friends_link&sk=8db8be3ebd2b2e2452fb9ef440a9cf7a) on managing dependencies in Firebase). Once your `mainTemplate.gradle` file is patched (another Force Resolve might be required), you can directly audit any Android dependencies you might have.

I hope something here helps!

--Patrick